# Working with pattern of list with values surrounded by {}

Tags: tcl

I have data that is `{} {abc}`, `{abc} {}` ,or `{abc} {def}`, and I want to capture it in 2 variables. I tried:

```
foreach {fname} <program to get values> {
    set dfrom [lindex $fname 1]
    set rname [lindex $fname 2]
    print "fname- $fname"
    print "dfrom- $dfrom"
    print "rname- $rname"
}
```

However, `{}` is not getting an index.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual about lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), emphasis mine:

> When presented with a single index, the lindex command treats list as a Tcl list and returns the index'th element from it (**0 refers to the first element of the list**)

So you will have to use something more like this:

```
foreach {fname} <program to get values> {
    set dfrom [lindex $fname 0]
    set rname [lindex $fname 1]
    print "fname- $fname"
    print "dfrom- $dfrom"
    print "rname- $rname"
}
```

And if you're on Tcl 8.5 or newer versions, you can use [`lassign`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm):

```
foreach {fname} <program to get values> {
    lassign $fname dfrom rname
    print "fname- $fname"
    print "dfrom- $dfrom"
    print "rname- $rname"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcl lists have indices beginning at zero.

You would do this in Tcl 8.5

```
lassign $fname dfrom rname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 8.4 or earlier, do:

```
foreach {dfrom rname} $data { }
```

foreach will do list based assignment so you don't even need anything in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

If the results come in pair you could:

```
To save an array to a file:
foreach {key value} [array get myArray] {
    puts $myFile [list set myArray($key) $value]
}
```

This would be a good start, the example was taken from: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1018

Nevertheless, if you want to collect the result using only the one fname variable you'll need to remember that **the index of the list starts at 0**.

```
foreach {fname} <program to get values> {
    set dfrom [lindex $fname 1]
    set rname [lindex $fname 2]
    print "fname- $fname"
    print "dfrom- $dfrom"
    print "rname- $rname"
}
```

However, if you are receiving a nested list, you'll need to first get into the list of index 0, then search it

```
foreach {fname} <program to get values> {
    set dfrom [lindex $fname 0 0]
    set rname [lindex $fname 0 1]
    print "fname- $fname"
    print "dfrom- $dfrom"
    print "rname- $rname"
}
```

font to look for lindex info: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1481